# Узнать текущий уровень зума в google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Вопрос в следующем:

В Google Maps нужно узнать текущий уровень зума. Через слушатель `map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener(){...});` не получается, выходит ошибка `deprecated`, т.е. все перечеркивается и возвращает в итоге `null`. А реализацию `OnCameraMoveListener()` не могу осуществить так как я еще чайник и мне нужны конкретные примеры. Либо же подскажите мне способ как сделать так, чтобы камера следовала за местоположением, но зум не менялся, а оставался всегда на уровне заданным пользователем. Ниже часть кода который отвечает за ведение камеры за текущим местоположением.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())) // камера следует за текущим местоположением
                        .bearing(myBear)
                        .zoom(15) //сюда я собирался подставлять переменную с текущим уровнем зума
                        .build();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16366852/3212712) пишут что надо так:

```
map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        int zoomLevel = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        //use zoomLevel value..
    }
});
```